# .[nodeTest] expression doesn't work

Tags: xslt, xpath

`xsl:apply-templates select=".[nodeTest]" mode="somemode"` fails with `could not compile select expression`.

I've re-read "Abbreviated Syntax" chapter in the specification and still don't understand if it's an implementation bug or an appropriate behavior.

`self::node[nodeTest]` of course works well.

Is it somehow specified that shortened self axis shouldn't work with predicate?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it somehow specified that shortened
>   self axis shouldn't work with
>   predicate?

**Yes, this is determined by the [grammar rules of XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-PathExpr)**:

```
[20]    FilterExpr    ::=    PrimaryExpr  
                            |  FilterExpr Predicate 


[15]    PrimaryExpr    ::=    VariableReference  
                              | '(' Expr ')'  
                              | Literal  
                              | Number  
                              | FunctionCall
```

As can be seen from these, `PrimaryExpr` cannot be `.`.

**This syntactic omission was corrected in XPath 2.0**, where the expression `.[someCondition]` is perfectly legal.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. It was posted before your edit. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: +1 Good answer. But for abbreviation purpose it could be `(.)[$predicate]`